# Remove application from IIS7 c#

Tags: c#, iis-7, web

I am trying to remove an application from the default web site in IIS7 during uninstallation. Here's my code which does not work:

```
Microsoft.Web.Administration.ServerManager iisManager;
iisManager = new Microsoft.Web.Administration.ServerManager();
Microsoft.Web.Administration.Site defaultSite;
defaultSite = iisManager.Sites["Default Web Site"];
Microsoft.Web.Administration.Application myApplication ;
myApplication = defaultSite.Applications["MyApplication"];

defaultSite.Applications.Remove(myApplication );

iisManager.CommitChanges();
```

What is the right way to do this?

Thanks

Comment: Try this: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/rakkimk/archive/2007/06/09/iis7-sample-code-for-adding-deleting-a-website-programmatically-c-example.aspx

Comment: That code should work, however you need to pass the right application Path, so maybe /MyApplication instead of just MyApplication.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

This should do the trick:

```
using (ServerManager serverManager = new ServerManager())
{
    Site site = serverManager.Sites["Default Web Site"];
    Application application =  site.Applications["/MyApplication"];
    site.Applications.Remove(application);
    serverManager.CommitChanges();
}
```

The code does make the presumption that you are deleting the application `/MyApplication` from the root of the `Default Web Site` (IIS number #1).

Comment: What do I have to do if I want to delete application's folder on hard drive?